# Search for a specific row in a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find a specific n'th row in a two dimensional array:

```
    public static String searchNum(int[][] playerArr, int[]winNum, int playerId) {
    // Take in an ID (row) and based on that, check the numbers against the winning numbers and display which category they fall.

    for(int i = 0; i < playerArr.length; i++) { // Loop over the rows (ID's)

        if(playerArr[i] == playerId)){ // If current row = input (player id)
            int currID = i;
            int counter = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < playerArr[i].length; j++) { // i = row
                int currLottNum = winNum[j];

                boolean contains = IntStream.of(playerArr[i]).anyMatch(x -> x == currLottNum);
                if(contains) {
                    counter ++;
                }
            }

            // Add to array depending on number of matches
            switch(counter) {
                case 6 : winners.add(currID);
                    break;
                case 5 : fifthPlace.add(currID);
                    break;
                case 4 : fourthPlace.add(currID);
                    break;
                case 3 : thirdPlace.add(currID);
                    break;
                default : losers.add(currID);
            }
        }
    }

    return strRes;
}
```

I'm trying to compare the row of a 2D array (playerArr[i]) against a given int but it's not letting me " Operator '==' cannot be applied to int[]"

Any help is appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Comment: You're comparing at the wrong level, `playerArr[i]` is an int array (the whole first row), which it doesn't make sense to compare to an int. That comparison belongs in your inner for loop.

Comment: I could see two issues here. one that you are trying to compare an integer array with an integer value. playerArr[][] is an integer array of 2 dimensions and playerArr[i] will give you an integer array of one dimension. Now you are trying to compare one dimension value with an integer value playerId. and the second issue you have an additional brace on the same line.

Comment: Why don't you use `Map` isntead of `array`?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele, Thank you, this makes sense, however. I'f i'm understanding correclty, I do not see how doing the comparison in the inner for loop will do it as playerArr[0][0] for example will give me the first element OF the first row and not the row number itself.

Comment: Why don't you use `Map` isntead of `array`? **You have to learn DATASTRUCTURES BASICS** Your code is absolutely incorrect from both as *Java* as *Data Strucutres* point of view

Answer (score 0):

As I can see **playerArr** is an 2D array and **playerArr[i]** will return an 1D array. So you cannot compare both. 
Now if you want to compare each player ID then your code should be like this :

```
public static String searchNum(int[][] playerArr, int[] winNum, int playerId) {
    // Take in an ID (row) and based on that, check the numbers against the winning numbers and display which category they fall.

    for (int row = 0; row < playerArr.length; row++) { // Loop over the rows (ID's)

        for (int column = 0; column < playerArr[row].length; column++) { // Loop over columns
            if (playerArr[row][column] == playerId) { // If current row = input (player id)
                // your logic
            }

        }
    }
    return strRes;

}
```